# How to run target after some commands in gnumake

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have Makefile like this:

```
b:  
        @echo "b" 

a:  
        @echo "a" 
        @make b
```

I want this Makefile to print "a\nb" after i execute 'make a'. It does the 
thing, but It also prints "Entering directory" and "Leaving directory":

```
$ make a
a   
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/bessarabov'
b   
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/bessarabov'
```

Actually that lines doesn't disturb me, but I'm not sure that this is the 
correct way of running some targets in the end of other targets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GNU make has a switch to silence the Entering/Leaving messages: `--no-print-directory`.  using `make` usually isn't right, you probably want to change it to $(MAKE).

rationale for $(MAKE) versus "make" is given in the GNU make manual [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/MAKE-Variable.html#MAKE-Variable) and [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options_002fRecursion.html#Options_002fRecursion)

Comment: Thank you. Writing `@$(MAKE) --no-print-directory b` instead of `@make b` did the trick. But why I should not use `make`?